# Global.asa hack

Tags: security, global.asa

Somehow somebody is hacking our global.asa file (IIS 7.5). We do not use our global.asa file for anything, but when somebody inserts code into it, it of course used.

Initially, we didn't even have a global.asa file on the site until somebody pushed it there.

While we're reviewing permissions, firewall, all other security measures, is there any quick way we can totally stop IIS from looking for the file?

Yes, our site is traditional ASP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding an empty global.asa and set the permissions to be very restricted, so basically only 'read' access to IIS_USR account

Comment: Dan but that's exactly what I had done prior to it happening a second time. Thank you for taking the time to try and help me out.

Comment: I have had the same issue and I have not yet discovered how it was done or what to do to prevent it, so any help you can give would be greatly appreciated